# MVC 4 GeneratePasswordResetToken how to generate a new one?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the following code to generate a reset Token

```
var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user);
```

it worked the first time, in that it updated the webpages_Membership table, and updated the following fields,

PasswordVerificationToken
PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate

but when I run the above code again, the token returned is the same, and nothing is updated.

how does it work?

Comment: The token will only refresh once it has been used with `WebSecurity.ResetPassword(model.ResetToken, model.TheUsersNewPassword);`. If you do not complete the full password reset process, the same token will always be generated for that specific user.

Comment: @X3074861X: this should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The token will only refresh once it has been used with `WebSecurity.ResetPassword(model.ResetToken, model.TheUsersNewPassword);`. If you do not complete the full password reset process, the same token will always be generated for that specific user.

If the password is not reset within 24 hours (default), then the above method will return `false`. If you want to override the default password expiration, you can add the optional parameter `tokenExpirationInMinutesFromNow` when calling `WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken` :

```
public static string GeneratePasswordResetToken(
     string userName,
     int tokenExpirationInMinutesFromNow
)
```

If you want to catch a bad password change attempt, just wrap `WebSecurity.ResetPassword(model.ResetToken, model.TheUsersNewPassword);` in a try catch block, and you'll be able to display an error to the user :

```
[HttpPost, AllowAnonymous, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       try
       {
           //Reset password using the reset token and the new password
           WebSecurity.ResetPassword(model.ResetToken, model.TheUsersNewPassword);

           //Redirect to the home account page.
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, LocalizedText.Account_Reset_Password_Error);
        }
    }

   //Something bad happen, notify the user
   return View(model);
}
```

I won't worry to much about catching a specific exception here, because the fix will be the same either way - they'll need to generate another password reset token.

Comment: what happens if the expirydate and time has been reached? would it create a new token then?

Comment: Yes, a new token would have to be created. I updated my answer to include this.

Comment: actually one question if time has lapsed, and you try to use WebSecurity.ResetPassword(model.ResetToken, model.TheUsersNewPassword); it doesnt throw an exception, it just returns a false.  How can I get it to throw an exception? I need to distinguish from an invalid token or if the time has expired

Comment: Thanks for that.. I duplicated your code, it never seem to go into the catch block, it always goes into the try and then goes to the Index View.  I placed a break in the catch, and gave the url a different token, or tried after the token had expired... it never goes to the catch